# Variable Variable in Twig

Tags: twig

I have the following variables in twig:( I can see them with kint)

```
data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color1 = '#008080'
data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color2 = '#00FFFF'
data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color3 = '#FFFF00'
data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color4 = '#FF0000'
data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color5 = '#FF00FF'
```

and

```
verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating = Returns [1-5]
```

How can I show the dynamic variable like this? Neither of these lines work:

```
{{_context['data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color' ~ verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating]}}

{{attribute(_context, 'data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color' ~ verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the variable you want to access is actually an array.
With your current code, twig is looking for a variable called e.g., `data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color.foo`, translated to `$_context['data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color.foo']`

To actually access the variable you want, you would need to treat the variable like an array:

```html
{{ {{ _context['data']['po_user_setting']['us_highlight_color'~ verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating] }} }}
```

This is quite long to type every time, so to reduce the typing you could use a macro or extend twig

---

*macro*

```html
{% macro get_array_value(context, key) %}
    {% set value = null %}
    {% for key in key|split('.') %}
        {% set value = loop.first ? context[key]|default : value[key]|default %}
    {% endfor %}
    
    {{ value }}
{% endmacro %}
```

As macro's don't have access to the special variable `_context` you would to pass this every time when you want to call the macro, e.g.

```html
{% import _self as macros %}
{{ macros.get_array_value(_context, 'data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color' ~ verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating) }}
```

---

*extending twig*

```php
<?php
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('get_array_value', function ($context, $variable) {
    $keys = explode('.', $variable);
    if (empty($keys)) return;
    $value = $context[array_shift($keys)] ?? [];
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $value = $value[$key] ?? [];
    }

    return !empty($value) ? $value : null;

}, ['needs_context' => true,]));
```

Then you can call this function like the following in twig

```html
{{ get_array_value('data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color' ~ verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating) }}
```

Comment: Thanks DarkBee, Very good explanation :-) I tried it for some reason, it doesn't work:  
`{{data.po_user_setting.us_highlight_color2}} -> #009FFF`  
`{{verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating}}       -> 2`  
`{{ _context['data']['po_user_setting']['us_highlight_color'][verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating] }} -> Returns nothing`

Comment: You correct, I've posted this without testing. The key of the variable you are after is `us_highlight_color1`, so I made a mistake there, the full written variable should be `{{ _context['data']['po_user_setting']['us_highlight_color~verse.po_verse_highlight.hl_rating] }}`. Adjusted this in the answer

Comment: [Full demo](https://www.darkbee.be/stack/array_variable/index.php) - Using an older version of Twig here, that is why the function is not namespaced

Comment: Oh My god! I don't know how to thank you! You're awesome :-)